# Which Better Beamer model for the Sigma EF-530 DG Super Flash

Tags: flash, sigma

I'm looking to order a Better Beamer flash extender for my Sigma EF-530 DG Super flash however, I can't find which model would fit it.  Anyone can point me to the right model?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing beat a visit to your friendly neighborhood photo store.  The model that fits is the FX-5.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this flashfinder](http://www.rpphoto.com/support/flashfinder/default.asp), the FX-2 fits the EF-500 Super, but the 530 isn't listed.

The same site also has a [fitting guide](http://www.rpphoto.com/flashextender/flashfit/default.asp) that lists dimensions and measuring instructions, though, and these seem thorough enough to double-check the fit.

Note - the site is *really* slow, so be patient.